# Instead of AdView an empty box appear( Android Element Layout Issue)

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I'm trying to place AdView to layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is showing correct my content and the boxholder in the bottom of view, there is supposed to be an adView, but i see empty box and ads doesnt appear.

In my logs, i see:

```
Ad finished loading.
W/cr.BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30285
Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.
Ad finished loading.
Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer for my question. XML was correct, just Adblock havent initialized in workflow. To do that, I needed just initialize in activity adMob block in onCreate Action:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Also import depreacted libraries:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Thank others for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Following are possible errors

1. Your Banner ad unit id is not correct
2. You have not set ad properly on Google ad mob follow below link
   [follow this link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638?hl=en)

If my answer resolve your issue, please vote up

Comment: Banner id and other stuff is correct, I'm using the same code snippet on other views. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have set the height of the inner `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`. THat will consume all of the available space leaving none for your AdView, so it will think it is not visible. CHange the LinearLayout to:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for response @William! Unfortunately, situation haven't changed. I still see empty boxholder for ads, but ads itself is not showing.